# Android folder to store media files and access them via an absolute path

Tags: android, storage

I'm working on an Android application that needs to store media (document files like pdf or so for later reading) but the main requirement is that all media files have to be accesible through an absolute path (a physical path on filesystem).

I'd like to avoid copying files to external storage (like sdcard or phone internal memory) so to prevent that if application is uninstalled those files remain in phone (and of course to avoid duplicating the size in kb for each file) and instead to keep files in iny App internal resources folder, but tried "file:///asset_folder" whith no success. As far as I know "file:///asset_folder" only Works for a webview to Access www folder but not for regular files.

I'm not sure if there is any app internal data folder which I can access through an absolute path or if not which is the best way to store App resource files.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: To make it more clear, the resource files are already bundled with the App, and not written during runtime, and what I'd like to know is where to put them so I can later Access them via absolute path for Reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrive your app specific data

```
openFileInput(file_name)
```

To save your app specific data

```
openFileOutput(file_name, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Update : Read from asset folder. (InputStream)

```
getAssets().open(fileName);
getAssets().open(fileName, accessMode);
```

check the image to where to put asset files
[image: asset_folder]

now to make other app readable your files from private data/data directory use content providers.

Comment: Hello Sush and thanks for your response, but I don't understand exactly the answer. For you to know, the resources (document files) will be shipped whith the App but what I don't know is in which folder should I put them so later on in when app is running they're accesible through an absolute path (the document reader is built in in the App too but its a library so I cannot modify it and it needs a phisical path to Access the document files)

Comment: @DiegoPerez Then best solution is asset only. Its accessible in android system

Comment: Thanks again sush, thats what I'm looking for, but how? You say the best solution is to use asset but how to do it? Because "file:///asset_folder/xxx" or "file:///asset_folder/xxx.xxx" doesn't work :s

PS. I guess you are talking about app asset folder right? (not working the way I describe)

Comment: oh ok. i understood ur problem i have updated my ans please take look.

Comment: Thanks again for being so kind sush, but not sure you understood.

I have developed an Android app, my app (among other things) reads books (lets say pdf files) but the pdf reader is an external library to which I pass a path and it opens and displays the pdf, so the input parameter should be a string with the path (for example /sdcard/download/xxx.pdf) but i'd like this path to be internal of the app and not external, so as building the project I need to store my pdf (resource) files so later the reader (the external library) can access and load them through a physical path.

Comment: Thanks sush, we are getting closer! I know where the assets folder is and I put the files right there, then as the library which reads the files is included in my app I just need a path to that assets folder as a string. Imagine the next example:

String complete_path_with_filename = "/assets/readme.pdf";
Reader reader = new Reader();
reader.openPdf(complete_path_with_filename);

This is a simple example of what I need.

Comment: Sorry for the delay sush. I wasn't at home and was able to test it late at nite.

The path "file:///android_asset/readme.pdf" is not working. As far as I know this path form is only valid for a webview and not for a normal file stored in assets folder, I was Reading a lot about it and they say assets folder doesn't have a physical path (that's why I started the post) but anyway I'll accept the answer as you did a great effort in helping me.

The key to my conclusión is if I call my library and pass a path like \sdcard\xxx.pdf and it opens the file but with file:///android_asset/xxx.pdf not.

Comment: check out my last line of edited ans. thats the solution for u.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44384/discussion-between-sush-and-diego-perez)

Answer (score 0):

You can not  write data inside asset_folder because it is packed on apk file. You can use sd card or location where your app is installed inside internal memory.

Comment: Hello Ajay and thanks, I don't need to write data, I already have the data and they are books (mainly in pdf) that will be included with the application, but I need to know where to store them when building the app so later on they are accesible through an absolute path.

To be more clear, my app is shipped with some pdf files that then the user can read, and the reader is a library that takes a physical path to the book as a parameter and just opens it.